# Why can't my Django app find my function in views?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm new to Django and am trying to create a simple "Hello World" webpage. I've set up a project and an application, but in the urls.py of my application it says that the function I've defined in views can't be found. Pycharm seems to not even recognize the two lines of my function because it says "expected 2 blank lines, found 1" although that may not be what that means. Any ideas are appreciated.

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(response):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World')
```

**from main(my app)/urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),
]
```

Comment: I see that you are a new user of stackoverflow. Please if/when you ask more question put your code in the post and not in an external screenshot. It makes it easier for people to replicate your issue and try and help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your urls file like this:

```
from .views import home

urlpatterns = [
  path('', home, name='home'), 
]
```

Comment: Doing this gives me another error: "Unresolved reference 'home'"

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Apparently, in Pycharm atleast, all function definitions must have 2 lines of space between them and other code. As you can see, I only had one line of space between my functon definition and my import on the line above in view.py.

Comment: Sorry, but the number of blank lines is a mere matter of style. PyCharm highlights it, because it's convention (in Python world it's called PEP-8) to have two blank lines. This does not by no means change the program logic. Also, the use of an IDE (PyCharm) does not have impact on errors of the program. So, you must have changed something else which fixed your problem :)